# Does Chinese Z visa obtained with a PU Letter restrict you to a province or city within China or are you free to travel from one province to another?

Tags: visa, china

I have an employer that will submit PU letter request for me, the employer is based in Chengdu and I also have a person that I want to see and stay with for a while after I enter China, the person is in Zhongshan, Guangdong, 1500 km away from Chengdu.
I have found out that I am required to apply for Residence Permit only in Chengdu but the employer didn't mention any other restrictions yet it was also brought to my attention that I need to register at the local security office and that even hotels that I book will file a form for temporary residence at local security bureau.

- Am I at risk if I want to stay and work remotely indefinetly from Guangdong province if my residence permit is from Chengdu?
- If I obtain the residence permit within 30 days can I look for a better job afterwards in Guangdong China or will my visa status be at risk if I quit the job that facilitated the z visa and residence permit?

Edit 1 - what i found on https://www.china-briefing.com/news/china-visas-explained/ :

Where a foreigner changes his/her job but continues to hold a valid work permit, he/she can undertake an “employer change” procedure with the government to renew the work permit. The actual procedure for the renewal may vary from city to city. In Shanghai, the main documentation required for such application includes:

- Two copies of the foreigner employment application form;
  A release letter from the previous employer (if the foreigner is relocated to Shanghai from a different city, government-released proof of work permit relocation/cancellation shall be provided);
- Valid business license, organization code certificate, FIE approval certificate (if the employer is foreign-invested) of the new employer;
- A curriculum vitae in Chinese, including the highest academic degree obtained and complete work experience;
- Work-related qualification certificate or proof of past work experience (issued by previous employers) that is related to the new employment;
- Academic qualifications;
- Employment contract with the new employer;
- The current work permit;
- Valid passport, residence permit, and employer’s employment permit;
- Three passport photos; and
- Other documents required by the government

Answer (score 0):

As a resident, you are free to travel around China, except for Tibet - you need a Tibet travel permit and to book a group tour. Feel free to explore China.